# find query returning all items in array despite querying only on one

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I am writing a query to act on only one item in an array, but the query is returning the entire array.

I have a collection with data like this:

```json
"testScenarioId":"100",
"testSteps":[

  {
     "edit":false,
     "controlId":1450419683150,
     "controlName":"scanTextBox",
     "objProp":"id->articleSearch_scanViewPopup_field",
     "objPropType":15,
     "action":{
        "id":6
     },
     "screenId":1450419663920,
     "screenName":"Order.Scan",
     "applicationId":4,
     "applicationName":"GSM",
     "testCaseId":"100",
     "index":1,
     "testStepNumber":"1"
  },
  {
     "edit":false,
     "controlId":1450419683894,
     "controlName":"scansearchbutton",
     "objProp":"id->articleSearch_scanViewPopup_field_HelpIcon",
     "objPropType":17,
     "action":{
        "id":2
     },
     "screenId":1450419663920,
     "screenName":"Order.Scan",
     "applicationId":4,
     "applicationName":"GSM",
     "testCaseId":"100",
     "index":2,
     "testStepNumber":"2"
  }]}
```

I would like to update collection based on the criteria `"testScenarioId" : "100"` and `"testSteps.testStepNumber" : "1"`; that implies that the first document in the testSteps array must be updated, as shown below

{

```
 "edit":false,
 "controlId":1450419683150,
 "controlName":"scanTextBox",
 "objProp":"id->articleSearch_scanViewPopup_field",
 "objPropType":15,
 "action":{
    "id":6
 },
 "screenId":1450419663920,
 "screenName":"Order.Scan",
 "applicationId":4,
 "applicationName":"GSM",
 "testCaseId":"100",
 "index":1,
 "testStepNumber":"1"
```

}

But to my surprise when I run this command:

```js
db.TestSteps.find({"testScenarioId":"100","testSteps.testStepNumber":"1"})
```

in the mongo shell, I am getting *all* the documents in the testSteps array.

Edit: I would like to know the Java code, to update a document in a array using the above mentioned criteria.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi razz and welcome to Stack Overflow. Remember, the criteria in your find query only determine which documents of the collection are returned; they don't affect which sub-documents (in the array) are included in the return.
To return just a single item from the array, you need to look at the [unwind operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) in an aggregation query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Query for documents**

You can use the [$ projection operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_) in the `projection` argument of `find`.

the syntax of the find command is:

```
find(query, projection)
```

So this should work:

```
db.TestSteps.find({"testScenarioId":"100","testSteps.testStepNumber":"1"}, { 'testSteps.$': 1 })
```

- Note that when you specify a `projection`, only the selected fields will appear, so if you need other fields to return as well, add them to your projection.
  Read more about projection [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)

**Update documents**

To update based on a searched array element, you can also you the $:

```
db.TestSteps.update(
  {"testScenarioId":"100","testSteps.testStepNumber":"1"},
  {$set: {'testSteps.$.new_field': 'hello world'}}
)
```

The [$ operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) in the $set targets just the **first array element** that was matched in the query.

**Getting the element using find, modifying it, and saving it back**

You need to:

1. Get the doc with the array element
2. Extract just the element from the doc
3. Modify the element to what you want
4. Save it back into the same position - overwriting the original element

```
var doc = db.TestSteps.findOne({"testScenarioId":"100","testSteps.testStepNumber":"1"}, { 'testSteps.$': 1 });
var the_element = doc.testSteps[0];
var updated_element = changeThisElement(the_element);
db.TestSteps.update(
   {"testScenarioId":"100","testSteps.testStepNumber":"1"},
   {$set: { 'testSteps.$': updated_element }}
)
```

Comment: Hi Marmor,
Thank you for your response.
The mongo shell command is working and i am getting one matching document. Now i want to update it through java, with the object i get from the UI. To be precise if I update a record in  UI, the complete record as an object will be passed to the java function to update as a parameter to get the record updated in the mongodb.
excuse me if i am not clear with my question.

Comment: ok, I've added code in js that should fit you, you need to translate to Java though. Haven't tested it, hope this works for you...

Comment: Thank you So much, you made my life easy :).
 i am able to write the logic

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) in your find query,

```
db.TestSteps.find({"testScenarioId":"100", "testSteps": $elemMatch: {"testStepNumber":"1"}})
```

Comment: Hi Vishwa,
Thank you for the query. the provided query throwing syntax error. I launched it, after modifying as below,
db.TestSteps.find({"testScenarioId":"100", "testSteps": {$elemMatch: {"testStepNumber":"1"}}})
I am still getting all the documents in the testSteps array

Answer (score 0):

you need to add projection.

```
 db.TestSteps.find( { "testScenarioId":"100"},{"testSteps": { $elemMatch: {"testStepNumber":"1" } } } )
```